# Launch tomcat from Maven with context.xml and injected password

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to set up a Maven pom.xml file such that it will

- build my war file
- launch tomcat with a context.xml that has a database resource
- set the username and password in that context.xml from settings.xml or a properties file

I need the username and password to be external from the project so that the sensitive info isn't stored in version control.

The Maven tomcat plugin is working fine if I hard code the username and password.  I put the context.xml fil in src/test/resources/tomcat/context.xml and configured the plugin to pull it from there:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration> 
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <contextFile>
        ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/tomcat/context.xml
        </contextFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've seen examples of putting the username and password in the .m2/settings.xml file as follows:

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>demo</id>
      <username>myUser</username>
      <password>myPassword</password>
    </server>
  <servers>
```

But I don't know how to "inject" those values into the context.xml.  I've putting the following in the appropriate points in my context.xml:

```
${servers.server.demo.username}
```

or

```
${servers.server.username}
```

but they're not resolving to the actual value.

What's the best practice for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'server' tag inside 'configuration' and specify its id as value. 
In your case this is a 'demo'.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration> 
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <contextFile>
        ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/tomcat/context.xml
        </contextFile>
        <server>demo</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you.  But what do I put in the context.xml file?  I tried ${servers.server.demo.username}, ${servers.server.username}, and ${username} and none of those worked.  They weren't replaced.

Comment: Based on 'server' tag inside 'configuration' Tomcat plugin will pull appropriate password and user name from .m2/settings.xml which is external to source tree.